# Breaking out of nested loops in javascript: throw vs return

Tags: javascript

when breaking out of Nested loops in javascript would it be better (as in faster, less problematic, or more popular) to break using a try-catch-throw like a lot of people do in python, or have a self-executing function that returns out of the loops?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

Comment: What's wrong with `break [label];`?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `throw` if you encounter a problem that means you cannot continue.

Use `return` to indicate you want to exit the function.

Using errors in place of control flow gives the wrong impression about your intent.